# How to define a file in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, filenotfoundexception

I need to use a xml file in my code,

in Java it looks like this:

```
File inputFile = new File("test.xml"); //Path: C:\Users\...
```

however, when i try the same in kotlin, it does not work:

```
val inputFile = File("test.xml")
```

I always get an "File not found" exception.
I can't find anything on google on how to include files with Kotlin.

Comment: where are you put the file please

Comment: If the file exists both should work perfectly well

Answer (score 0):

```
val inputStream: InputStream = File("test.xml").inputStream()

val inputString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
println(inputString)
```

***Source*** : [kotlination.com](http://kotlination.com/kotlin/read-file-kotlin)

**The file must be in the root of your project**, the same folder containing your src/ folder.

Comment: I have tried all of this and it still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

These should give the exact same results, if you run both with the same working directory. You can check or set the working directory (relative to which `file.xml` will be looked for) in the Run/Debug configuration.

Since you have Android Studio tag: if you are creating an Android application/library and want the file to be included with it, you should read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html.